# "Closed" tag - should we have it?

Tags: discussion

I saw someone went and started removing tags from closed questions and tagged them with [closed](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/closed)

I'm pretty sure that "meta" tags such as this are essentially banned on other SE sites. Jeff doesn't go so far as "ban" them outright, but he does "[explicitly discourage](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)" them.

So what reasons does everyone have for a "Closed" tag? Is that enough reason to keep it?

Answer (score 8):

There should not be a [closed](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/closed) tag. There's no reason for it, as you can search for [closed questions](https://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed:1) fairly easily without it. And it's always a bad idea to remove valid tags.

I've rolled back the edits that added it and removed valid tags.

The [closed](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/closed) tag itself should be deleted during tonight's cleanup run.

Charles, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this person was me. I did not know that you could enter a "closed:1" into the search to bring these up. I was just trying to create an easy way to find closed questions Just curious, what does that ":1" stand for? Is there a way to make this apparent to people who aren't in on the secret?

Sorry for any frustrations I caused with my new tag.

Comment: No frustrations, Matt, just wanted to make sure we kept everything clean. As for the ":1", that would mean "true". In standard boolean logic, 1 is true and 0 is false. So if you wanted to get all open questions, you could use "closed:0". I know there are other keywords you can include that work this way as well when searching, but I don't know what they are. Maybe there's a list somewhere on [metase].

Comment: Awesome, I suspected that but had no idea search would interpret code.Thanks!

Comment: The advanced search operators can be viewed here: http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/search